# Can a discrete subset of $\mathbb R$ have a limit point within itself?

Tags: general-topology, limits, proof-verification, real-numbers

I have $S\subset \mathbb R$ , namely the set $$S=\left\{ (m+{1\over |p|},n+{1\over |q|})\right\}$$.Then I see that the set $$K=\{(m,n):m,n \in \mathbb Z\}$$ is the set of all **limit points** of the set $S.$

Now the question is can $S$ be discrete ? If $S$ were discrete then every point of $S$ would be an isolated point, which, in this particular context is not happening. It has limit points within itself so this is not discrete.  I hope I'm right. Opinions please. Thank you.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam:So? $\mathbb Q$ is not discrete .

Comment: @AbdallahHammam: And how is that related to my post in any way ?